# get a specific value in gridview column on mouse click asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

[image]

Get the value of each string on mouse click asp.net, not the entire line each word like when i click on மருள் i should get மருள் in a label

Comment: Nice!!!! Tell us more about it!

Comment: its like string between characters if i click on a word it should show the word the delimiter is before and after space example if i click on துமிய in the last line we have to capture the word by before and after space

Comment: You could split the strings  for every space and save all of them in a List of strings like this `Dim x As New List<String>(input.Split(" "c))` 
Then retrieve the first element.

Comment: its in gridview i can click on any word not only the first, if i click i have to capture the string between spaces

Comment: loop through the list<string> and print a LinkButton for every string, then set as `CommandArgument` the `LinkButton.Text`.

Then in the `LinkButton.onClick` event handle the selected string.